# Chrome and FF Downloads Embed URL Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I have an embed set up on my page as such

```
<embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

When loading the page chrome prompts for the location to download the file.

The php serving the file does use the inline header

Even [PDF Object](http://pdfobject.com) is not working in either browser but does work in safari

I am using a mac but I have confirmed the same results on windows

Comment: NM didn't notice you already tried PDF Object, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome on a Mac, hope it helps.

```
<head lang="en">
    <script src="js/pdf.js"></script>
    <script>
        PDFJS.getDocument('read_me.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
            // Using promise to fetch the page
            pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                //
                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                //
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                //
                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                //
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

paraphrased from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js

Cheers,
PJ